# Вывод данных через циклы

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Стоит простая задача на php вывести таблицу, именно циклами.

```
F
E F
D E F
C D E F
B C D E F
A B C D E F
```

Но мой код выводит немного не правильно, не помаю что не так.

```
<?php

$str = "70";
$Fstr = '69';

for($i=0; 6>$i; $i++){
    echo "\n","<br>"; 
    for ($j=0; $j < (0+$i); $j++) { 
        echo chr($Fstr);
        $Fstr--;
    }
    echo chr($str);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ну так у вас переменная `$Fstr` уменьшается за каждый проход цикла, а судя по выводимым данным, должна заканчиваться одним и тем же значения на каждой строке. Вам нужно переместить `$Fstr` внутрь первого цикла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
    $Fstr = '70';
    $acc = '';
    
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) { 
        $acc = chr($Fstr) . $acc;
        $Fstr--;
    }
    
    echo $acc, "\n","<br>";
}
```

Переменную `$Fstr` надо сбрасывать каждый раз на очередном заходе.

Чтобы данные помещать перед предыдущим сообщением я объявил переменную аккумулятор, в которую добавляю значение в начало

Плюс ещё дописал условие `$j <= $i;` вместо `$j < $i;`